# How to add id automatically in SAS

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

I have the following SAS code:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE HUB_Addresses (
    AddressID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LOAD_DATE NUM FORMAT=DATETIME22. NOT NULL, 
    RECORD_SOURCE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL   

   );

RUN;
quit;
```

But AUTO_INCREMENT is not working. How can I fix it

Comment: ' not working' - do you get an error message? or is it not incrementing as expected

Comment: This question has been asked. The answer is you can't.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937584/i-want-to-add-auto-increment-column-in-a-table-in-sas

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add other columns and run.

```
CREATE TABLE `HUB_Addresses` ( 
    `AddressID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 

    PRIMARY KEY (`AddressID`)) 
    ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

RDBMS features found in other systems, such as Oracle, SQL Server or Netezza:

- <strike>auto_increment</strike> not in SAS SQL
- <strike>triggers</strike> not in SAS SQL
- <strike>default values</strike> not in SAS SQL
- <strike>sequences</strike> not in SAS SQL

If your data design depends on `auto_increment` you will have to use a third party data base and the appropriate SAS/ACCESS engine to interact with it.

`Proc SQL` lacks the listed features because the default Base SAS library engine (V9) does not support such features.

If you already have a `MySQL` connection available and a SAS/ACCESS engine to interoperate:

- SAS/ACCESS to MySQL or
- SAS/ACCESS to ODBC with MySQL ODBC drivers installed

You can use **pass-through** syntax to submit MySQL statements directly to the data base server.

```
libname REMOTE MYSQL … connection options …;

PROC SQL;
    connect using REMOTE;

    execute (
      /* MySQL statement */
      CREATE TABLE HUB_Addresses (
      AddressID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
      LOAD_DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
      RECORD_SOURCE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    ) 
    by REMOTE;

    * insertion occurs through SAS/ACCESS engine via REMOTE libref;
    insert into REMOTE.HubAddresses 
      values (., '01FEB2010'D, 'Manual insert')
    ;
```